# Force graphics to run on specific GPU

Tags: xorg, nvidia, graphics, hybrid-graphics

My computer has one integrated graphics card and 2 Nvidia RTX 3070 GPUS. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and `nvidia-driver-530`.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1)
```

I am currently trying to test my 3070 graphics cards with the Phoronix Test Suite.

I am using `nvidia-prime` and `prime-select: on-demand` to run the terminal on the intel iGPU and phoronix tests on the Nvidia 3070: `prime-run phoronix-test-suite run unigine-heaven`.

There were some issues getting `nvidia-prime` to work, so I followed the suggestions from this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364762/prime-run-command-not-found

```
cat /usr/bin/prime-run
#!/bin/bash
export __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1
export __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
export __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only
export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json
exec "$@"
```

By using `prime-run` I am successfully able to run the phoronix test suite on GPU 0 which has bus id `01:00.0` / `PCI:1:0:0`.

However, I seem unable to run any tests with GPU 1 which has bus id `05:00.0` / `PCI:5:0:0`.

Modifying `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` by changing the bus number and rebooting as suggested by the following links didn't seem to do anything and still ran on GPU 0.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382271/how-can-i-modify-xorg-conf-file-to-force-x-server-to-run-on-a-specific-gpu-i-a
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/787030/setting-the-default-gpu

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 530.41.03

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
#    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

In fact, I deleted `etc/X11/xorg.conf` and was able to run the phoronix tests on GPU 0 without the conf file at all. I would guess that one of the drivers or programs I run automatically selects the nvidia card with the lowest bus id.

I would like to know where I should look to change the settings or any configuration files in order to select the second RTX 3070 gpu with the bus id `05:00.0`. I would be more than happy to provide any further information.

Comment: Better ask here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: I have done that, and I'm currently working on a solution on the Nvidia developer forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `prime-run` script, I also need to set the variable

`__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD_PROVIDER=NVIDIA-G{CARD#}`

using the card identifier found in `xrandr --listproviders`.

The official Nvidia guide listed below has the resolution to this problem, but I did not read the guide closely enough and missed it on my first read.

https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/495.44/README/primerenderoffload.html

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is unnecessary for this solution.

I missed the part about the `OFFLOAD_PROVIDER` because I was accessing the headless server remotely from a client without any Xsession or graphics display.

The machine must be running some type of GUI and not just a headless terminal environment. In my case, I installed `lightdm` onto my server and then everything worked.

I believe that the graphics needs to be using `x11`/ `xorg` and not `wayland`. For `gdm3`, `xorg` can be set to run by uncommenting

`#WaylandEnable=false`

in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and rebooting.